# How to refer to class from inside package in Java

Tags: java, maven, import, package

I have maven project which src folder contains 2 packages and 1 class outside this packages.

[image: project structure]

Inside MainWindow i want to create ClientConnection instance but it cant resolve symbol 'ClientConnection'. Is this possible to create this instance without moving file inside 'GUI' package ?

Comment: Could you please make your image smaller. I almost can read its contents.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels [too bad SO does not allow images in comments](https://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic4.fjcdn.com%2Fthumbnails%2Fcomments%2FSmallsmall%2Btext%2Bi%2Bdont%2Bevensmall%2B_4249dd13375300eb8850b75863d4ad43.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Ffunnyjunk.com%2Fchannel%2Fgameofthrones%2FMy%2Bdream%2Bgame%2FxhGqGku%2F10&docid=sia5xlv5_42ulM&tbnid=5nphLwiR2YhXTM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjZ3q37vcPYAhUJ5qQKHS1VBxwQMwg_KAswCw..i&w=300&h=168&bih=759&biw=1536&q=small%20text&ved=0ahUKEwjZ3q37vcPYAhUJ5qQKHS1VBxwQMwg_KAswCw&iact=mrc&uact=8) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new package (e.g. `connection`) in `java` folder and move `ClientConnection` to package `conenction`. In your `MainWindow` add

```
 import connection.ClientConnection;
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes in the default package cannot be imported by classes in packages.
You need to create a package for all your classes. It's best practices.